# Dockerfile for Spark/Java application to execute via Spark Operator

Tags: java, docker, apache-spark, google-spark-operator

I am trying to run spark/java application on kubernetese (via minikube) using spark-operator. I am getting a bit confused on what should I place in the Dockerfile so that it could be built in the image format and execute via spark-operator ?

**Sample spark-operator.yaml :**

```
apiVersion: sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: my-spark-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: Java
  mode: cluster
  image: docker/repo/my-spark-app-image
  mainApplicationFile: local:///opt/app/my-spark-app.jar
```

As mentioned above, the spark operator yaml only requires the jar and the image location. So, do I need to mention just below in my Dockerfile ? Is there any sample Dockerfile available which I can refer ?

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM openjdk11:alpine-jre

COPY target/*.jar /opt/app/csp_auxdb_refresh.jar
COPY src/main/resources/*  opt/app
```

Comment: did you able to get valid DockerFile and spark-operator.yaml ? If yes can you please share those 2 files ? I'm also in need of the same.

Answer (score 2):

In the `Dockerfile` you have provided, nor Spark, nor other dependencies are installed.
To quickly get started, use `gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v3.1.1` as the base for your image, i.e. change the `FROM` statement to `FROM gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v3.1.1` and build again.

There is a great guide on how to get started with the `spark-operator` in their Github repo ([here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/docs/quick-start-guide.md)).